# Testing backbone.js application with jasmine - how to test model bindings on a view?

Tags: javascript, view, backbone.js, jasmine

I had some interesting tribulations in trying to test whether views were correctly bound to events.  In backbone, we typically bind to events in the initialize method, using something along the lines of: `something.bind("change", this.render);`.  In my test, I want to make sure that this binding is set up, so I did the following:

```
this.myView = new MyView();
spyOn(this.myView, "render");;
this.legendView.groupData.trigger("change");
expect(this.legendView.render).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But, that won't work.  Because the bind occurs in MyView's initialize function, the event get's bound to myView's render function AT THAT TIME.  So, when you add your spy, it wraps the render function and sets it back into place at myView.render.  But the closure created by the first bind still exists, and we are totally hozed.  So what can we do about it?  What I did, is move my bind call's to a seperate function, something like:

```
myView = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, "render");
    this.initialize_model_bindings();
},
initialize_model_bindings: function(){
    something.bind("change", this.render);
},
render: function(){ //... }
});
```

and my test then looks like:

```
this.myView = new MyView();
spyOn(this.myView, "render");
this.myView.initialize_model_bindings();
this.legendView.groupData.trigger("change");
expect(this.legendView.render).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This works, but I'm looking for a better solution.  Thanks

Comment: Do you mind explain this point "But the closure created by the first bind still exists, and we are totally hozed" again? I'm having the same problem and trying to understand what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: When you call `new MyView()`, the initialize method gets called, and the render function that exists in the object at that time is bound to the change event.  From that point on, it's impossible to access the render function which is bound to the change event - it's locked into the closure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of spying on the callback you might try spying on something.bind. Then test that bind was called w/ the appropriate arguments. This is working for me so far. I'm using sinon.js instead of jasmine's built-in spies. sinon.js makes it a bit easier to test for args passed to a method call in a stack of same method calls (eg a bunch of calls to bind in a view init). So I haven't tested this idea w/ jasmine alone but believe it should be possible.

```
spyOn(this.legendView.groupData, 'bind');
this.myView = new MyView();
expect(this.legendView.groupData.mostRecentCall.args).toEqual('change', this.myView.render); // example!! only works if testing a single call to bind or the last call in a series (ie mostRecentCall)
```

And w/ sinon.js

```
sinon.spy(this.legendView.groupData, 'bind');
this.myView = new MyView();
expect(this.legendView.groupData.bind.calledWith('change', this.myView.render); // works w/ any number of calls to bind
```

Answer (score 12):

I have managed to achieve this using prototype patching. Before you create the instance of the view, `spyOn` the constructor's prototype.

```
spyOn(MyView.prototype, 'changeSelected');
var view = new MyView();
view.selectSomething();
expect(view.changeSelected).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: for some reason this worked for me only using `sinon.spy(...)`. thanks for this hint!

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by spying on a function called by my render function. So in your example:

```
myView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, "render");
      something.bind("change", this.render);
  },
  someOtherFunction: function(){},  //this function only called from render
  render: function(){ this.someOtherFunction(); /* rest of render function */ }
});
```

test looks like:

```
this.myView = new MyView();
spyOn(this.myView, "someOtherFunction");
this.myView.something.trigger("change");
expect(this.myView.someOtherFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

then I wrote a separate test for whatever someOtherFunction does.

Comment: That seems like not a terrible solution, but I find that my render functions change quite frequently.  I feel like I'd be updating my specs quite a lot if I did this.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider looking at Sinon.js.  You could stub/mock the render() call and not even have to worry about 'someOtherFunction()'.

Answer (score 1):

This may be too closely coupled with Backbone internals, but you can check the callback chain manually:

```
expect(this.legendView.groupData._callbacks['change']).toContain(this.myView.render)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and changed my Views code from:

```
this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
```

to:

```
this.model.on('change', function () {
    this.render();
}, this);
```

And my jasmine tests worked as expected.